# Bundler Error - http.rb:799:in `connect': SSL_set_tlsext_host_name: (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I migrated the gems from ruby-1.9.2 to ruby-1.9.3 and then tried to run bundle install.  When I did, I got the error above.  Any clue as to why?

Using rvm 1.9.2, ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux], bundler 1.1.4, and rubygems 1.8.24

```
Error stack:
user@linux-kt6v:~/rails_projects/rails_app> bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler 
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks! 
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect': SSL_set_tlsext_host_name: (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `block in connect'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:750:in `start'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:224:in `connection_for'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:358:in `request'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:145:in `fetch'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:173:in `fetch_dependency_remote_specs'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:132:in `fetch_remote_specs'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:70:in `specs'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/source.rb:234:in `block in remote_specs'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `each'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `remote_specs'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/source.rb:165:in `fetch_specs'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in `specs'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb:53:in `__materialize__'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:86:in `block in materialize'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `map!'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `materialize'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:122:in `resolve_remotely!'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/installer.rb:48:in `run'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/installer.rb:12:in `install'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in `install'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.1.4/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need some updates:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash # get latest RVM
rvm reload                # load installed version 
rvm autolibs enable       # enable automatic libraries installation
rvm remove 1.9.3          # remove installed ruby
rvm install 1.9.3         # install it again - including proper libraries
```

Comment: I can't confirm or deny that your solution works, mpapis.  The machine I was using it with died.  However, for anyone who comes across this issue, I was able to get bundler to work by using "http" instead of "https" in the "https://rubygems.org/" the top of the Gemfile.